# Copy folders that match names to other sub folder of matching directory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy folders from one directory to the sub directory of another folder if the folder names match.

The starting folder structure is like this -

```
Data > VR-01
```

The entire `VR-01` folder should be moved to the destination folder is like this -

```
Data > VR-0-1000 > VR-01 [match this name] > Archive > [matched folder (VR-01) should go here]
```

The VR's are separated out into different folders, 0-1000, 1001-2000, etc. with the same directory structure.

```
$startPath = "C:\Start\Data"

$destinationPath = "C:\Destination\Data"

$DestinationFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath -Directory | Select -ExpandProperty FullName

# for each item in the folder that is a directory (folder)

Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse -Directory | %{

    #Get the folder name to compare it to the destination folder
    $CurrentFolderName = ($_.Name) 

    #Find matching directory for that folder

    #Where-Object 
    $DestinationFolders | ?{$CurrentFolderName -like $DestinationFolders} 

    #Copy files
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationFolders -WhatIf
}
```

I've tried using the `-match` command and it failed due to the \ character being part of the regex from what I can tell, so I switched to `-like`.

It looks like I'm missing a step in comparing the folder names and copying them, because from the `-WhatIf` command I see that it is just copying the folders over to the first subfolder without matching the name.

Comment: I can't grep a structure neither from your description nor from your code. BTW there still is the `tree.exe` utility to visualize structures.

Comment: I apologize for not making it more clear.  The structure would like the answer below. 

`C:.
├───Dest
│   ├───VR-1-2
│   │   └───VR-01
│   └───VR-3-4
│       └───VR-03
└───Start
    ├───VR-01
    ├───VR-02
    ├───VR-03
    └───VR-05`

Comment: Well comments are just for ... comments or short code snippets enclosed in backticks. **Please** [Edit] your quetion to contain additional (properly formatted) information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I visualise your description is that in the Destination\VR-0-1000 folder, you want to copy the source VR-01 if a VR-01 subfolder exists in VR-0-1000. There may not necesarily exist a `Destination\VR-0-1000\VR-n`.

I had a stab at it. Not guaranteed for efficiency, but I believe it will do the job.

```
$startPath = "C:\Start\Data"
$destinationPath = "C:\Destination\Data"

$sourceNames = (Get-ChildItem $startPath -Recurse -Directory).Name

(Get-ChildItem $destinationPath -Directory).FullName | % { 
    # For each folder named 'VR-****-****'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | % { 
        # For each folder named VR-****-****\VR-****
        if($sourceNames -Contains $_.Name)
        {
            $sourceFolder = "$startPath\$($_.Name)\*"
            $destFolder = $_.FullName
            Write-Output "Copying $sourceFolder into $destFolder"
            Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $destFolder -Recurse
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it on a structure like so

```
C:.
├───Dest
│   ├───VR-1-2
│   │   └───VR-01
│   └───VR-3-4
│       └───VR-03
└───Start
    ├───VR-01
    ├───VR-02
    ├───VR-03
    └───VR-05
```

Output:

```
Copying C:\soverflowtest\Start\VR-01\* into C:\soverflowtest\Dest\VR-1-2\VR-01
Copying C:\soverflowtest\Start\VR-03\* into C:\soverflowtest\Dest\VR-3-4\VR-03
```